# Reduce Team Foundation Server database space

Tags: tfs

I have some large projects hosted in Team Foundation Server 2010 Source Control. This projects are long time so many check-ins will occour and as we make check-ins the database grows up.

I'm afraid that size will be a problem in the future (including performance and backup space/upload time).

Is there some way to reduce this size (deleting old changesets or something else)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, there are a couple of ways to clean your TFS database, and these solutions target different components of TFS such as Version Control or Test Management. AFAIK, there is no unified way to control the growth of the TFS database.

These tools are:

[tf destroy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx)

[Test Attachment Cleanup Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/19/managing-tfs-2010-how-to-clean-up-test-attachment-data.aspx)

[witamin (destroying work items)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236908.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For many files TFS stores a delta of the changes, not full copies every time you check-in. This can greatly reduce the size of the database. You may be worying abount a non-issue.

Comment: The TFS undoubtedly make a great work in storage source code, changeset and so on. The question is more about my own curiosity than a real worry. In the docs there's nothing about that, but the docs don't cover many other useful tricks.